# Composite Key in HashMap, with a don't care relation for one of the values

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to design a HashMap which has multiple Strings/Enum's as composite key. I want to change the functionality, such that if the map is filled with an enum/string value as "default", then it will match to anything in the search

The Key here is matching anyvalue to "default", if the specific value does not exist.

let's say the following class is the Key class of this HashMap:

```
class KeyClass{
  String val1;
  String val2;
  String val3;
}

HashMap<KeyClass, String> randomMap = new HashMap<>;

randomMap.put(new KeyClass("abc", "default", "efg"), "value1");
randomMap.put(new KeyClass("abc", "def", "efg"), "value2");
randomMap.get(new KeyClass("abc", "wef", "efg")); // should return "value1" as "wef" should match to default, 
randomMap.get(new KeyClass("abc", "def", "efg")) // should return "value2", as it explicitly matches
```

Specifically I'd like design suggestions for such a Map structure (for instace would it work with two different maps etc.) , or how to implement the hashCode function for such a key class if it is at all possible.

Comment: Could you elaborate where exactly would this implementation be useful, i.e. give a real usage example?

Comment: @MickMnemonic- I have a lookup dictionary for some workflows, certain workflows are very specific and need all values to be specified, in other cases the workflows are not dependent on part of the input of the composite key. 
Dependency is not known at search time, but only when we are updating the table. i.e. workflow 1 depends on all values, while workflow 2 is the same regardless of value in the second parameter

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible if I understand your question correctly. I think you need to use something else than HashMap for this.

HashMap uses the `hashcode`/`equals` methods of the key-class for matching, so I interpret your question as how to implement those methods.

`hashcode` is actually easy. I think your only option would be to return a constant. This is a stupid idea, but it would be necessary if "default" should match anything.

`equals` is not possible to implement. The matching you describe would not be symmetric and transitive as required by the documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: agreed does anything beside a HashMap fit this problem? I'm open to alternate suggestions for a data structure